# Build step to create nuget package using CoApp (Write-NuGetPackage)

Tags: powershell, msbuild, nuget

I'm following http://blogs.techsmith.com/inside-techsmith/nuget-packages-3/

I have a native c++ project I wish to publish to a nuget feed.

I install the powershell tools, create my autokpg file and test it works from the package manager console. It works, I get my 'nupkg'es out.

I now want this as part of the build process so I add

```
Write-NuGetPackage C:\...\myproj\myproj.autopkg
```

to the post build events in the project properties

To my post build step, but it seems MSBuild can't find Write-NuGetPackage as it returns

> ":VCEnd existed with 9009."

What's the "correct way" of solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Execute a Powershell script in your post build event.

Add a powershell script to your project.  Something like **yourpowershellscript.ps1**.  Inside of it add your command to execute the Write-NuGetPackage.

```
Write-NuGetPackage myproj.autopkg
```

Then in your post build event execute the sript.

```
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -file $(ProjectDir)\yourpowershellscript.ps1
```

When you build the output from CoApp will be displayed in Visual Studio's output window.

```
Attempting to build package from 'myproj.nuspec'.
Successfully created package 'D:\Dev\myproj\myproj.7.1.0.nupkg'.
Attempting to build package from 'myproj.redist.nuspec'.
Successfully created package 'D:\Dev\myproj\myproj.redist.7.1.0.nupkg'.
Attempting to build package from 'myproj.symbols.nuspec'.
Successfully created package 'D:\Dev\myproj\myproj.symbols.7.1.0.nupkg'.
```